# Colored columns in ChartKick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

So I am displaying a column chart, it has date along the x-axis, and time taken on the y-axis.

It displays build times, but sometimes builds failed (build_state from the model can either be "Successful" or "Failed")

I want to show the Successful bars to be green, and the Failed ones to be red.

This is how I get the data:

```
@column_chart_result = @bamboo_results.pluck(:build_start_time,:build_duration_minutes)
```

And then create the chart:

```
<%= column_chart @column_chart_result, colors: ["green", "red"], width: "600px" %>
```

Obviously it displays all the bars as green, I'm not sure how to add in logic to show build_state and have successful as green and failed as red?

Comment: Are you using Highcharts or Google Charts?

Comment: How hard would it be to switch to Highcharts? I have a solution ready to go in Highcharts; it's a little easier to do more complex things like this.

Answer (score 0):

All of this is assuming you're using Highcharts. I'd recommend you use Highcharts; it's a little bit easier to do more complex things like this:

[image]

Here's what you need to do:

```
@column_chart_result = @bamboo_results.pluck(:build_start_time, :build_duration_minutes, :build_state)

# Take out the :build_state column for Highcharts:
@highcharts_data = @column_chart_result.map {|n| [n.first, n.second]}

# Build an array of colors
@highcharts_colors = @column_chart_result.map {|n| n.build_state == "Successful" ? "green" : "red" }

<%= column_chart @highcharts_data, colors: @highcharts_colors, width: "600px", library: {"plotOptions": {"series": {"colorByPoint": true }}} %>
```

I've tested a similar approach on my own (different) dataset. Of course, I haven't tested it on *your* data set. Let me know if it throws errors or otherwise doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the code and modified the view to use this line:  

<%= column_chart highcharts_data, colors: highcharts_colors, width: "600px", library: {"plotOptions" => {"series"=> {"colorByPoint"=> true }}} %> 

but still its all green, any ideas how to use in gcharts?